# How do I remove a certain file from my pycharm project?

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm community edition and I have an existing project where I added a folder by:

```
Pycharm > Preferences > "Project name" > Add content root
```

What that did was add all existing files in that folder into my project. That included output data, PDF files and other stuff in that folder into the project.

How do I exclude certain files from the project/project window but not delete that file?